Help choosing right chainset / crankset - commuter looking for a faster top speed
I need to replace the chainset on my commuter bike and I'm thinking of a change.
I've currently got Shimano: 28/38/48 front,  11-32 (8 cogs) back.
My daily cycle (north to central London and back) is 10km in a straight line each way. I never change out of top gear on the front (3) and really only use between 3/4 and 3/8. I generally cruise in 3/7. When the wind is with me (most days one direction) I'll be in 3/8 wanting a faster gear.
Whilst 99% of my cycling is this flat route, I don't want a bike that can't go up hills when I need to :)
According to the chap in the shop I have plenty of room for more cogs on the back.
He thinks I should go for one cog on the front and more range on the back.
To me, this doesn't seem sensible due to the angle of the chain. Is it not better to have more cogs at the front so when in top gear the chain runs in a straighter line? Because of this, I still feel I should have three on the front.
I've been loving this gear calculator: https://www.gear-calculator.com/?GR=DERS&KB=36,42,52&RZ=11,13,15,18,21,24,28,34,40,48&UF=2135&TF=90&SL=1.9&UN=KMH&DV=teeth
And based on this, I think I probably want 52 teeth at the front / 11 on the back which would give me an extra 10% top speed compared to now.
But the big front cogs (sorry, poor terminology throughout this post!) seem to mostly come in twos eg the Shimano 52/36.
And I being silly looking for three on the front? Should I just go for 52/36 front with 11-34 back?
Thought greatly appreciated!
===
Update (sorry for delay) - in the end I went for the double chainring 52/36 and I'm really happy with it! Still reach the top gear most days but don't find myself needing more. Occasionally use the smaller chainring so happy I've got it as an option. Thanks everyone for your help.

Typically, in the front, we say chainring. Cog typically refers to the rear. We do know what you mean, though.

@WeiwenNg Sprocket. Cogs interact without chain. Cogs inside Sturmey.

Thanks, some people do say sprocket. Plenty of people say cogs, however.

Shuriken perhaps?

Hi Jamie, If you are going to replace it with a compact together with new crank sets, make that the crank uses the same size standard as your current BB spindle, otherwise you may have issues with the chain line.

A bit late here, but what's limiting your speed?  You haven't really said that.  80 RPM while in 48/11 gearing gets you 44 kph, which is a pretty brisk pace to sustain if you're not doing a UCI-sanctioned race.  And 80 RPM isn't a high cadence at all - it's actually on the low side, even for long-term sustained cadence.  Do you have longish slight descents where you spin out and can't pedal any faster?  Do you need bigger gear(s) for sprinting in competitive group rides?

Thanks Andrew, lost in the comments but summary is: very much a commuter, not a racer! Understand low cadence is more efficient but I just really enjoy cruising fast while peddling slow! Hoping you guys will indulge me :)

Have you any way to measure your cadence?   Or accurately measure your speed and work backward.

@criggie I don't have anything to measure cadence, but I do now have a phone mount giving me a good speed guide (bought for my first long cycle recently - London/Essex 100 miles - 4 x further than I'd ever cycled before)!
On my 100 miles I didn't use my top gear, I averaged 18.9 mph (excluding 3 stops) mostly using the big chainring - 52 teeth - and roughly cog 7 out of 9.
On my commute I seem to cruise at 24-6 mph on the flat, and that's when I happily use the new top gear. I'll let you work out how low that cadence is if you'd like :)

@JamieG based on https://www.bikecalc.com/archives/speeds-at-cadence.html you'll have a cadence of around 75 in 48:11 at top speed, which is not bad at all.  Slower than racers who aim for 90+ but more than the 55-60 cadence I anticipated.

There is quite alot to unpack here.
Single chainring (The cog at the front), (Often called 1x, meaning "1 times" rear cogs vs 2x or 3x) has been around for a long time in the MTB world and taken over, but the user benefits are largely limited to novices and riders who struggle with front and rear gears.  The push for 1x came from frame designers and reduces assembly costs. Net is it is an advancement over 3x and 2x, but on an existing bike, not so much. I would not, especially if your goal is higher gearing for flat roads.
Another thing to consider is we get a lot of questions on this site asking how to get taller gears so the person can go faster. Unless you are pedaling at a cadence of 90-100rpm, the cheapest and most efficient way to go faster is to learn to pedal faster.
Next consideration is cost. Usually, it is not cost effective to make big changes to a bike that is not a newish bike of high quality. Given your bike is 8 speed, it is probably quite old. You may be better to consider selling it and using the funds from the sale and what you would need to spend to buy another bike
If you are going to go ahead and make changes to the bike, it does get a little complicated.  There are limits on the maximum size chainring the front derailleur can cope with, as well as the maximum the read derailer will cope. You can usually get away with exceeding these a little (especially with Shimano who are quite conservative). You need to ensure the larger chain ring fits the frame without rubbing.
If all that can be made to work, a 54/36 front would be a good choice. For the cassette much would depend on the state of the existing rear cassette, if it is worn and need changing, then I might consider 11-34, but you could go to 52/34 front and get a similar low gear
Edit: In response to the comment asking for clarification on chain angles, chain angles are not a problem. Some people believed chains angles were a problem back in the day, and a few still cling to past beliefs. Technology has moved on, chains are more supple, lubes much better, the increase wear of 'cross chaining' might be measurable in a lab under ideal conditions, but where the rubber meets road, the additional wear is marginal. Chains are a consumable, they wear out, and are more likely to wear form poor lube or lack of cleaning than cross chaining.

Subject to frame clearance, there a cranksets like 30/39/50, which would help a little

Thanks @mattnz really appreciate the reply. I'm going for "I'm going to fix my bike, might as well aim to get it a touch closer to how I want it". It is indeed an old bike: v brakes, child seat, falling apart saddle... the list goes on, but... all the more fun for overtaking shiny lycra clad cyclists with their clip-in peddles and clickity-clickity cassettes :) And yeah, I enjoy cycling more when peddling slowly but going quickly, so it's enjoyment over logic I guess.

I think I probably do need to replace the rear cogs due to wear. I will check on the clearance I've got for a bigger chainring - good thought. I wasn't totally clear on your 1x vs 2x vs 3x. I think you were saying that I should not go 1x, but your recommended 2x. Is that just because 3x is harder to come by, or was there other reasoning too?

How important is cost? You may be able to get a 52 tooth in a 104BCD chainring that would bolt onto you existing crank (is it 4 or 5 bolt).  3x on speed is probably better as going 2x you probably get big steps between gears to too small total range. In 10speed+ world, go 2x.

You're being overly critical of 1x here. It gets rid of an ugly cludge that was used to advertise bikes as "21-speed" when only 10 of these 21 speeds were useful. Now with 11- and 12-speed cassettes we've matched and exceeded old drivetrains on both range and step.

No, I am not against 1x at all. I am against people saying that old bikes benefit from an upgrade to 1x without qualification.  Specifically, I will ask "what problem does the OP have that 1x solves? "

@Therac the biggest range I can find for 1x is 500%.  I've got 515% on my touring triple, and 618% on my MTB triple.  And 502% when I fit the new cassette to my 2x11 gravel setup.

@Chis H Where are you looking, if the biggest range you could find is just 500%? Standard MTB 1x range is 510% for Shimano and 520% for SRAM.

@ChrisH You can get 578% for SRAM drivetrain: https://singletrackworld.com/2019/04/12-huge-cassettes-for-1x-drivetrains-that-arent-shimano-or-sram/

@Therac so still quite a bit less than I've got with cheap components, and using a 9-tooth cog.  I hope the 9s and 10s are available  separately because they'll last no time at all

@airace3 Standard 1x12. 12 speed is pretty high end. A quick google showed lots of 10-50 and 11-52.  I wonder if google knows I'm more interested in 11s, where 10-50 is a stretch, because if I specify 1x12 I do see the sort of thing you find.  I reckon I could push my 3x9 setup to over 700%, but I don't want (much) more at the bottom end - as it is I was alternately losing traction and lifting the front wheel on Sunday in my lowest

The difference between the theory and practice is the OP has to pay for it.  Maybe he has the cash for a 1x12 upgrade of his '1990's technology' 3x8speed, but unless he has a strong emotional attachment to the bike, I would advise against it.

I wasn't emotional until you said "1990's technology" :p

In general though, no one appears in the least bit concerned about chain angle - which was my worry with less front chainrings, but I'm taking from this chat I shouldn't be concerned at all. (But also v. interested in Mattnz and Chris H's suggestion of just replacing the outer chain ring).

@ChrisH Just for your update: 1x12 in flat bar world starts with Deore and can be found on 800€ bikes, so not "pretty high end" ;) (but personally, if going 1x on a commuter, I would rather go to CUES than Deore — for the data that the OP gave, staying on 3x8 seems anyway the best option).

@Renaud things have moved faster than I thought for new sales.  Even my friends with newer bikes than mine are mostly on 1x11, but we don't tend to be the sort of people to buy new very often.  So I'm seeing a sample of what was commonly sold a few years ago, when 1x12  was high end

With many, but far from all, cranksets you change change individual chainrings, keeping your triple.  Fitting a bigger one to replace the 48, the front derailleur will have to move up a little.
So to figure out your options, you first have 2 things to check:

Are the chainrings bolted together or riveted?  Chainring bolts don't look like bolts at first glance.
How is the front derailleur fitted? Many clamp on with a band, some are brazed on and can't easily move.  If band-on, check that there's nothing in the way.  I wanted to change mine to a different model for greater tyre clearance, but would have have to file off a bottle cage boss.

If the chainrings are riveted, you need to change the whole crankset, and if doing that, you need to make sure the new larger inner chainring(s) don't touch the frame.  However you could go for a double crankset or even a triple but remove the inner ring.  Just be sure to set your low limit screw so you don't accidentally drop the chain.
If they're bolted, you can replace just the outermost, being sure to match the number of bolts and their BCD (bolt circle diameter, AKA PCD for pitch circle diameter) and re-position the FD.  Just going from 48 to 50 you might get away with the FD position, going to 52 it's unlikely.
Now I'm a fairly low cadence rider myself, so I'm hesitant to say this, but at a typical 80rpm, your numbers imply that you're not dropping below 30km/h and reaching 45 km/h.  I haven't ridden much in London (and I'm normally 200km into the ride when I do) but cars can't generally go that fast at typical commuting times so you must be flying past them.  If you're not, that suggests a very low cadence and you might work on spinning faster.

Thanks Chris, just had a proper look. I've got this: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/334156443328
Seem like bolts to me, but also doesn't seem like something that expects to be upgraded! I'm up for it if you think it'd work though. I'm unsure how to know what would be compatible though.
The derailleur is a clamp - looks easy to move.

PS. It's bus lane all the way, so very start/stop due to traffic lights, but easy to get up to speed with higher cadence, then cruise contentedly at 35-40 km/h in top gear for a minute until the next lights. Repeat.

You might want to have a look at WolfTooth's BCD guide and compare to what you've got

Great, will measure! Thanks
